Swift Package Manager stuck on loading screen forever
SPM loads indefinitely as seen below. I cannot add any packages.
Whether I enter a URL, or don't enter a URL, this screen is loading forever.
Have tried deleting DerivedData folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData) as well as SPM caches (~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/), does not help.
Have made sure that I've committed my code to a git repository, and followed the advice here.
This is the first package I'm adding—I can't add any packages, generally.
This problem exists for all my Xcode projects.


I faced the same problem in Xcode 16.1. These two solutions worked for me, but I must repeat them every time I add a new Swift package (SPM).
The first way:

When you are on the loading SPM screen, press command + delete/backspace to clear the SPM history.
Clear the history. enter image description here
After that, I can add a new SPM.

The second way:

Close Xcode completely. Ensure it’s not running in the background.
Open the Terminal and run the following command to remove cached Swift Package references: plutil -remove IDESwiftPackageAdditionAssistantRecentlyUsedPackages ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
Reopen Xcode and your project. You should now be able to add a new Swift Package without any issues.


Second way worked for me!

First way worked for me.

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by removing all my source control accounts under Xcode -> Setting -> Accounts and adding them back.

Just tried this and it didn't work. Thanks for the tip though.
